# Gerar tabela dinamica com TCPDF

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, tcpdf

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o `TCPDF` para gerar um relatório de avaliação, e preciso que esse relatório seja dividido nas semanas que o usuario tiver atividade.

**No momento o relatório esta assim**
[image: Como o relatorio esta gerando]

O que eu preciso é percorrer o array, começando na segunda feira e terminando no domingo, quando chegar no domingo preciso fechar a tabela e começar uma nova da segunda feira, gerando novamente o cabeçalho e as atividades do dia, porém não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

---

#### Function que gera o relatório

```
public function gerar_relatorio($__cod)
 {

    $sessao = $this->session->userdata('portal');

    $ativ_semanal = utf8_string_array_encode($this->atleta_model->get_atividade_semanal($__cod));

    $nome_atleta = $this->atleta_model->get_atleta($__cod);

    $borda = 0;

    $header_titulo = array('SEG','TER','QUA','QUI','SEX','SAB','DOM');

        for($j = 0; $j < count($header_titulo); ++$j) {
        $this->pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 255);
        $this->pdf->SetTextColor(255);
        $this->pdf->SetDrawColor(0, 0, 255);
        $this->pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);
        $this->pdf->SetFont('', 'B');
        $this->pdf->Cell(25, 6, $header_titulo[$j], 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    }


        $this->pdf->Ln();

        $this->pdf->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
        $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->pdf->SetFont('');

           $ultimo_dow = 1;
    $x = 20;
    $y = 39;
    $contador = 0;
    $cont = 0;
    $ultimo_dia = 0;
    $ultimo_dia_semana = 0;
    $num_atividades_semana = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($ativ_semanal); $i++) {
        $this->pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
        $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->pdf->SetFont('');
        $num_atividades_semana = $ativ_max[$ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana];
        if(($ativ_semanal[$i]->num_dia - $ultimo_dow) > 1){
            /* Esse bloco printa os intervalos maiores que 1 até que chegue em um dia preenchido */
            $cont = $ativ_max[$ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana] - $contador;
            for ($j=0; $j < $cont; $j++) { 
                $this->pdf->SetFillColor(100, 100, 150); //Roxo
                $this->pdf->SetY($y);
                $this->pdf->SetX($x);
                $this->pdf->Multicell(25, 15, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                $y += 15;
            }
            $ultimo_dow += 1;
            $ultimo_dia_semana = $ativ_semanal[$i]->num_dia;
            $x += 25;
            $y = 39;

            $contador = 0;
            if ($ultimo_dow != 7) {
                $i--;
            }
        }else{
            /* Printa a partir do ultimodow encontrado acima */
            if ($ativ_semanal[$i]->num_dia == $ultimo_dow) {
                $this->pdf->SetY($y);
                $this->pdf->SetX($x);
                $this->pdf->Multicell(25, 15, $ativ_semanal[$i]->descricao, 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                $y += 15;
                $contador+=1;

                /* Dia da semana que possui o maximo de atividades da semana */
                if (($ativ_max[$ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana] - $contador) == 0) {
                    $contador = 0;
                    $y = 39;
                    $x += 25;
                    $ultimo_dow += 1;
                }
                $ultimo_dia_semana = $ativ_semanal[$i]->num_dia;
            }else {
                $cont = $ativ_max[$ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana] - $contador;
                for ($j=0; $j < $cont; $j++) {
                    $this->pdf->SetFillColor(90, 255, 255); //Azul claro
                    $this->pdf->SetY($y);
                    $this->pdf->SetX($x);
                    $this->pdf->Multicell(25, 15, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $y += 15;
                }
                $ultimo_dow = $ativ_semanal[$i]->num_dia;
                $x += 25;
                $y = 39;
                $contador = 0;
                $ultimo_dia_semana = $ativ_semanal[$i]->num_dia;
                if ($i != count($ativ_semanal)-1) {
                    $i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

     if ($contador == 0) {
        $x += 25;
        $y = 39;
        $contador = $ultimo_dia_semana;
    }else{
        $x -= 25;
    }

    $x -= 25;
    $contador = $ultimo_dia_semana;
    for ($i=0; $i < (8-$contador); $i++) { 
        $cont = $contador - $num_atividades_semana;
        for ($j=0; $j < $cont; $j++) {
            $this->pdf->SetFillColor(0, 50, 255); //Azul Escuro
            $this->pdf->SetY($y);
            $this->pdf->SetX($x);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(25, 15, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $y += 15;
        }
        $x += 25;
        $y = 39;
        $contador = 0;
    }

    $this->pdf->Output($nome_atleta[0]->nome.'_'.date("d/m/Y").'.pdf', 'I');
    return;
 }
```

---

#### Exemplo de retorno com os dados para montar a tabela

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#26 (7) {
   ["dia_semana"]=>
    string(7) "Segunda"
   ["num_dia"]=>
    string(1) "2"
   ["data_hora"]=>
    string(16) "26/11/2018 15:20"
   ["num_semana"]=>
    string(2) "48"
   ["descricao"]=>
    string(3) "Seg"
 }
}
```

Comment: Você consegue salvar os dias da semana em números ? Acho que fica mais fácil, assim você percorre o array de 0 a 6 onde 0 é domingo, e ai você quebra o relatório quando acabar esse for, gerando uma nova linha.

Comment: os dias da semana estão sendo salvos em números. Porém a semana inicia com 1 = domingo

Comment: Vou postar como comentário, por que tenho ciencia de que não é o que perguntou. Porem depois de muito tempo, resolvi gerar a a partir de html, e isso facilitou muito minha vida e tempo de desenvolvimento. As manutenções passam a ser muito mais simples tambem. https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/. Você montar o HTML dinamico é mais facil do que gerar o PDF diretamente

Comment: Sem sucesso mesmo utilizando HTML, o problema esta na lógica.

Comment: Ele é uma cópia do [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/): 8o! Só que eu acho que é mais completo.

Comment: Você pode usar mod:  `if ($i % 7 == 0) ` e fazer o `continue;` no for... daí vc aplica para cada semana, e inicie seu array com `$i = 1`, faça o `for ($i=1; $i < count($days_month); $i++)`

Comment: Você pode fazer algo [como isso](http://ideone.com/fJdgT5).